What does '[' after an argument in a call function signify in Python?
I have been going through the opencv wiki when I came across the resize function defined as:
dst = resize( src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]] )

I am unable to understand what the [ after the arguments signify.
I was assuming that it means an optional argument, but I realized that cannot be the case as dsize is a required argument.
Any clarification would help a lot.

The argument(s) in the [] is/are optional, dsize isn't enclosed in brackets.

Okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! But if we are looking at it that way, why are the commas within the brackets needed?

The commas are just  separators for visual clarity. As you use more libraries and tools, you’ll notice this is a common convention.

@s3dev Is there any place online to learn more about these design choices?

It comes from the Backus-Naur-Form, a way to describe programming language grammars. As it is a grammar thing and the commas are part of the grammar, they are enclosed in this way.

The commas are not just separators for visual clarity. They are part of the syntax. It's better to think of it this way: you can drop anything enclosed in a pair of matching brackets and get a valid syntax of the function. This means resize(src, dsize) is valid because it can be derived by dropping anything enclosed in the outermost pair of brackets. resize(src, dsize, dst) is also valid and can be derived by dropping the next outermost pair of brackets, but not resize(src, dsize, fx). You should conceptually group things by square brackets and take the comma as literal.

This is just following typical Python documentation notation, as covered by the documentation.
The relevant part is quoted below for reference (emphasis mine)

The descriptions of lexical analysis and syntax use a modified Backus–Naur form (BNF) grammar notation.
...
... A star (*) means zero or more repetitions of the preceding item; likewise, a plus (+) means one or more repetitions, and a phrase enclosed in square brackets ([ ]) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional).

Note that when talking about the syntax, the comma is not special in any way and should be treated as a literal.
Let's first consider an example from the itertools documentation page to see why the commas are enclosed in the square brackets in this particular way. In the table, the parameters of itertools.islice() is specified as seq, [start,] stop [, step]. Four possible function prototypes can be derived from it depending on the number of occurences of each group:
0 and 0 ocurrences:
islice(seq, stop)

0 and 1 occurences:
islice(seq, stop, step)

1 and 0 occurences:
islice(seq, start, stop)

1 and 1 occurences:
islice(seq, start, stop, step)

You can see that the comma has to be organized in this way with respect to the square brackets in order to derive all the four syntaxes correctly. If for example the grammar were written as seq, [start,] stop, [step], with the comma outside the second bracket, then for the 0 and 0 occurences case we would obtain islice(seq, stop,), resulting in a redundant comma.
The syntax in the question can be interpreted in exactly the same way. The key point here is at the formal grammar level, the comma is just a literal, you should not consider  dst[ as a whole, which is where your confusion comes from.
For example, if we choose one occurence for the outermost bracket and zero for the others, we derive one possible syntax.
dst = resize( src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]] )
                        1     0    0    0               0001 
-> dst = resize( src, dsize, dst )

Another choice leads to another valid syntax.
dst = resize( src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]] )
                        1     1    0    0               0011 
-> dst = resize( src, dsize, dst, fx )

and so on. Now it should be clear why the comma need to be positioned in the way shown.
As already commented by others, Backus-Naur form is very common and not limited to Python. The details of modifications that Python made to the original BNF grammar can be found in the link above.

This is quite insightful. Seems like I should go through the Python documentation more often.

The square brackets [ ] in the OpenCV documentation typically denote optional arguments. However, in the case of the resize() function signature you provided, it's a bit confusing because dsize is indeed a required argument, as you correctly pointed out.
The square brackets are used to indicate optional arguments in the function signature. Let's break down the signature:
dst = resize( src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]] )

src: This is the source image you want to resize. It's a required argument.
dsize: This is the desired size of the output image. It's also a required argument.
dst: This is the optional output image. If provided, the resized image will be stored here.
fx: This is the scale factor along the horizontal axis. It's optional.
fy: This is the scale factor along the vertical axis. It's optional.
interpolation: This specifies the interpolation method to use. It's optional.

So, in essence, the only two required arguments are src and dsize, while the rest are optional. The square brackets around dst, fx, fy, and interpolation indicate that they can be omitted, and the function will still work, using default values or inferring them based on the provided arguments.

Furthermore, the nesting of the brackets indicates that dsize is not optional if you want to specify dst, etc.

Perhaps also note that this isn't a Python convention; in fact, the usual convention in Python is quite different, and somewhat less expressive.

This is just a computer science convention when optional nature of something is expressed by putting it in brackets. Unfortunately in this context, it leads to more confusion.

This is just a computer science convention when optional nature of something is expressed by putting it in brackets.
For example see the man page for grep
grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]

Unfortunately in this context (describing a python calling sequence), it leads to more confusion. It would have been better to use =None to indicate default parameters or use separate lines to describe various valid calling sequences.
